# import { CardStyleInterpolators } from 'react-navigation-stack' is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation **4.0.10** and react-navigation-stack **1.10.3** and trying to implement CardStyleInterpolations for android. According to the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator to implement this i have to do something like this

```
import { CardStyleInterpolators } from 'react-navigation-stack';

// ...

static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Profile',
  cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid,
}
```

and i'm implementing this with a functional component like this

```
Login.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid,
  };
};
```

because the static navigationOptions is for class component.

that looks simple but it's throwing me an error **undefined.object evaluating CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid** I guess this is related to incorrect import. Anyone knows how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here stackoverflow.com/questions/48018666/…. You just have to change the import from the answer to import CardStackStyleInterpolator from 'react-navigation-stack/src/views/StackView/StackViewStyleInterpolator'; for v4